# MVC3 - Conditional View Rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rendering, conditional-statements

I have a conditional business logic that determines whether a property from a model should be displayed in a view. according to best practices where would be the place to implement it?

Implementing this logic in the view level does not seem right to me.

Thanks

Comment: Question defines the answer with "Conditional View Rendering" means condition should be in the View rendering somewhere.:)

Comment: Logic inside the view means a complex view with no testing abilities and repeated logic for each view that has to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it is belonged to the Model. I would put that business logic in `IsRequiredYourProperyName` property in the model.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Really? I would have thought that would be fine in the view provided you're passing the boolean indicating whether or not it should be displayed as part of the ViewModel. The view shouldn't be querying an outside resource to see if it should render certain UI elements, but if everything it needs to determine what to render is in the ViewModel, what's wrong with a simple if{} statement? Alternatively if a conditional display property is common you could create a custom DisplayTemplate or EditorTemplate and for it and implement the logic there.

So your ViewModel should wrap everything you want to send to the view. in your case it sounds like it should wrap your DomainModel and some sort of dictionary or KeyValuePair collection detailing if each property should be displayed or not as booleans. That's what I would do anyway.